# Stop bash if any of the functions fail in parallel

Tags: bash, ubuntu, parallel-processing

I have a BASH to run 3 functions in parallel in my BASH.

```
        functionA () {
            ......
            my command || { echo "ERROR!!" >> $LOG_FILE ; exit 1 ;}
        }

        functionB () {
            ......
            my command || { echo "ERROR!!" >> $LOG_FILE ; exit 1 ;}
        }
       
        functionC () {
            ......
            my command || { echo "ERROR!!" >> $LOG_FILE ; exit 1 ;}
        }

functionA &
functionB &
functionC &
wait
```

I have some commands in all functions for Error handling like this:

```
my command || { echo "ERROR!!" >> $LOG_FILE ; exit 1 ;}
```

I noticed even though I have exit 1 for Error handling in all functions but the other functions still keep going. How do I stop bash and return exit code 1 if any of the functions fail?

I am very new to BASH, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since the parallel processes don't know about each other, my approach would be to wait until one of them terminates, check the exit code, and if it is non-zero, kill the remaining (running) ones. To manage this, I would use an array where I would store all the PIDs of those background processes which are still running.

Comment: @user1934428 Could you elaborate? I'm interested on how you can wait independently for each sub-process to finish while catching their exit code; the `wait` builtin doesn't seem to allow it.

Comment: @Fravadona : See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update:** Testing my original code with a large number of sub-processes terminating at the same time showed that some kind of exclusive locking mechanism is needed; I implemented a simple one (that is atomic) using the widely available `mktemp -d` and a symlink.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

lockdir=$(mktemp -d) || exit "$?"

trap 'exit 1' ABRT
trap 'mv "$lockdir" "$lockdir~" && rm -rf "$lockdir~"; kill 0' EXIT

diex() { ln -s _ "$lockdir/.lock" 2> /dev/null && kill -ABRT "$$"; }

{ sleep 1; echo "ERROR!!"; diex; } &
{ sleep 2; echo "HELLO!!"; } &

wait
```

<sup>**note:** Here I assume that `"$lockdir~"` doesn't exist. If it isn't good enough for you then you can create an other directory with `mktemp -d` and use it as a trash-bin before deleting it.</sup>

###### Explanations:

The idea is to make the sub-processes notify the main script with `kill -ABRT "$$"` when they fail.
I chose the `SIGABRT` signal because it is appropriate for the purpose of aborting, but it has the effect of disabling the automatic generation of the core-dump normally done when receiving `SIGABRT`. If you're running an OS that supports `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` then you can use it instead.

1. At the start of the script, you define some signal listeners with `trap` and associate a command to be run when catching a signal of the specified types:

- The listener for the `EXIT` signal (triggered for example by an `exit` command in the main script context) will terminate the script and all its sub-processes with `kill 0`.
- The listener for `SIGABRT` (sent by the sub-processes) will not only generate an `EXIT` signal but also set the exit status to `1`.

2. The locking mechanism is to prevent more than one `SIGABRT` signal to be sent.

Comment: Took a while to integrate your suggestion into my code. It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to ear that you could implement it in your code. Did you also add a locking mechanism? It is necessary to prevent too many sub-processes "signaling" the main script at almost the same time, which would result in the script going zombie and the other sub-processes continue running; you only need one signal for terminating the script.

Answer (score 2):

**GNU parallel `--halt-on-error now,1`**

GNU parallel is a winner for this kind of application. Install:

```
sudo apt install parallel
```

Test it:

```
myfunc() {
    echo "start: $1"
    sleep "$1"
    [ $1 -eq 3 ] && exit 1
    echo "end: $1"
}
export -f myfunc
parallel --lb --halt-on-error now,fail=1 myfunc ::: 1 2 3 4
echo "exit status: $?"
```

Outcome:

```
start: 3
start: 1
start: 2
start: 4
end: 1
end: 2
parallel: This job failed:
myfunc 3
exit status: 1
```

So we see that `4` never finished because `3` failed before it.

The:

```
start: 3
start: 1
start: 2
start: 4
```

appear immediately, `end: 1` after one second, and `end: 2` after another second, and after another second the final:

```
parallel: This job failed:
myfunc 3
```

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.

Notes:

- there was some conflict with moreutils parallel on Ubuntu previously: https://askubuntu.com/questions/12764/where-do-i-get-a-package-for-gnu-parallel but that is gone, `sudo apt install parallel` just works
- `man parallel` documents that:

  > For backwards compatibility these also work:
  >
  > 2           now,fail=1

  some on some earlier versions you might have needed `--halt-on-error 2` instead
- `export -f` makes things works on Bash by exporting the Bash functions as environment variables: [GNU Parallel and Bash functions: How to run the simple example from the manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814360/gnu-parallel-and-bash-functions-how-to-run-the-simple-example-from-the-manual)