# In bash, how to wait for one of two subprocesses to finish successfully, then kill the other?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

What is the idiomatic way in a shell script (bash preferred) to run 2 (or more) subprocesses in parallel, and upon one of those processes ending successfully, terminate the other(s)?

Specifically:

Start subprocesses A and B in parallel, then:

- If A finishes first and is successful, terminate B and return success.
- If B finishes first and is successful, terminate A and return success.
- If either finishes first but is unsuccessful, return the result of the other.

For my use case, terminating is important because A and B both consume resources that I would like to release as soon as possible.

(Suggestions to *not* use a shell script or use some other language are not helpful, because I need this idiom to run in an environment that I do not control and I would like it to be maximally portable to environments with, say, bash>=4.)

[Edit: added this clarification about the word *idiomatic*:]

Ideally, a solution would be *idiomatic* in the shell ecosystem, and play nicely with shell constructs such as functions, scopes, etc.  Using `wait_for_first_successful` as a placeholder, here's how it might be used:

```bash
function example() {
  function fn_A() { ...possibly many steps... }
  function fn_B() { ...possibly many steps... }
  # Next step runs fn_A and fn_B in parallel...
  wait_for_first_successful fn_A fn_B
  # ...and at this point, neither fn_A nor fn_B are running...
  result=$?  # ...and this is 0 iff fn_A or fn_B was successful.
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Can you install binaries for this? Specifically `parallel`.

Comment: Do you have a new enough bash to have `wait -n`? -- reading the changelog, it was introduced in 4.3.

Comment: @Uberhumus, ...that would be major overkill. parallel isn't just a single binary, it's a big mess of perl (that starts a whole new shell for each child process it runs instead of exec'ing those children directly); why would you use it for something the shell has built-in?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 1 - Because the moment you're used to it `parallel` is quite comfortable for shell scripting. 2 - Because I don't have another solution in mind? Looking forward to seeing your solution. I might learn something. :)

Comment: @Uberhumus -- I haven't used `parallel` before, but I see that it's a one-file program (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#one-file-program), so it would probably be trivial to ship it in the same Git repo as the script I'm writing (and therefore not require the _environment_ to provide it).  What would that solution look like?

Comment: @Mickalot, note that parallel requires the environment to provide perl. I'll admit, though, that that's not _too_ heavy a lift -- perl is probably at least as common as bash itself, though it's getting less ubiquitous over time -- as long as your licensing terms / corporate policies / &c allow you to ship GPL-licensed components as part of your codebase.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, I get that `parallel` requires `perl` and that it's not quite following the guidelines of the problem as I framed it.  But it is true that this lives in a Git repo, so I'm guessing there's an incredibly high probability that _some_ version of perl is lying around, so as long as I don't need to worry about which version it is, or install any extra dependencies beyond that single `parallel` file, or fiddle with PERL5LIB, etc., it _might_ be ok.  And it would allow me to keep the rest of the pre-existing shell script in shell.

Comment: @Mickalot Also have a look at `parallel --embed`.

Answer (score 4):

The **GNU Parallel** solution would look like:

```
parallel --halt now,success=1 python script.py {} ::: 1 2 3
```

which will run:

```
python script.py 1
python script.py 2
python script.py 3
```

in parallel until any one succeeds, then kill the remaining two.

---

You can also halt on a percentage of successful tasks rather than on an absolute number. You can equally halt on failures. You can also halt immediately killing other running processes, or halt by not starting any more once the currently executing ones finish... and so on.

Comment: Hmm...do all the children need to be the same executable?  What if one is `scp $file_src $tmpfile1` and the other is `wget $url -O $tmpfile2`?

Comment: You should be able to use `parallel - halt now,success=1 ::: 'scp something' 'wget somethingelse'`

Comment: Am realizing that one shortcoming of this approach is that `parallel` does not execute in the shell environment, so one cannot use a shell function as either of the subprocesses.

Comment: @Mickalot Run `export -f myfunc` then you can. Or use `env_parallel`.

Comment: @Mickalot If you need the output in shell vars, look at `parset`.

Comment: `env_parallel` references:  https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html and https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/src

Answer (score 3):

An other solution would be to make the sub-processes "signal" the parent when they complete successfully; the parent can then "terminate" all the remaining children.

```bash
trap 'echo "$(jobs -p)" | xargs kill; exit 0' SIGUSR1

{ cmd_A && kill -SIGUSR1 "$$"; } &
{ cmd_B && kill -SIGUSR1 "$$"; } &

wait

exit 1
```

**remark:** If you fire a lot of sub-processes then you'll need to implement some locking mechanism for ensuring that only one child can send the signal; check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71778627/3387716)

Comment: This is a clever idea -- the code (in its current state) isn't quite turnkey, but there's probably some kind of solution for some category of use cases that can be built off this approach...

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to do this in bash. The more efficient of those shown below requires bash 4.3 or newer; the less efficient will work in any version still in widespread use, including (unfortunately) 3.2.

The bash 4.3 approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[0123].*|4.[012].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.3+ needed" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

pids=( )
cmd_1 & pids+=( "$!" )
cmd_2 & pids+=( "$!" )

wait -n; first_rc=$? # wait for either child to die, capture its exit status

# kill whichever children weren't already dead
# as a good citizen we're using SIGTERM to let them clean up gracefully
# ...an extension might give them a fixed amount of time to complete, then
# escalate to SIGKILL.
kill "${pids[@]}"

wait              # wait for remaining processes, just killed, to exit
exit "$first_rc"  # exit with the exit status of the first to complete
```

---

The less efficient / more portable approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Do this only if you need compatibility with bash releases
# too old to have wait -n (before 4.3)
pids=( )
cmd_1 & pids+=( "$!" )
cmd_2 & pids+=( "$!" )

# adjust to taste, but non-GNU systems may not allow non-integer times
while sleep 1; do               # poll for exited children
  for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do   # loop over known subprocesses
    if ! kill -0 "$pid"; then   # kill -0 -> "are we still running?"
      wait "$pid"; first_rc=$?  # not running: collect and store exit status
      break 2                   # 2 -> break out of both the for and the while
    fi
  done
done

kill "${pids[@]}"  # once we reach here, one of our children is complete
exit "$first_rc"   # exit with the status of the first to finish
```

---

Note that PIDs aren't deallocated until their parent `wait`s for them, so when using `wait -n` the processes *other* than the one `wait`ed for are still in the process table as zombies (and their PIDs aren't free'd for reuse), and `kill -0` doesn't free things it finds to be dead at all.

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick response and multiple options -- very interesting!  Am trying them out locally now...

Comment: For others reading this solution, perhaps this is good background reading:  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html

Comment: OP probably wants to wait for the second child to finish normally if the first failed.

Comment: Yeah, both solutions need something like `wait -p` to understand which job finished?  Is that a bash 5-ism?

Comment: @Mickalot, you can figure out who finished by seeing for which process `kill -0` says it's dead.

Comment: @Mickalot, ...but yes, `wait -p` was introduced in bash 5.1.

Comment: As @Philippe points out, as the code is (currrently) structured, this doesn't solve the stated problem.  However, between the code and the comments, this is certainly an interesting approach that perhaps one could evolve into a solution.